# Rails 500 error in log, 404 page returned and no error description

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have an application running on NGINX/Passenger in production environment. Most of the pages render fine, but some do not. The server returns the static 404 error page, but when checking the production log, the following is appended:

```
Started GET "/upload" for 92.111.174.132 at 2015-11-26 14:07:50 +0000
Processing by Upload::StaticController#index as HTML
  Rendered upload/static/index.html.erb within layouts/upload (1.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8.0ms
```

Note that there are no error messages or backtraces; this is really all there is. I've checked NGINX's error log and it does not report an error. I really don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Why don't you post some code?

Comment: We really can't help you unless you post some code!

Comment: Because I don't know what code there is to blame! I thought maybe there is some method to get more log info.